# How to call a function for every position within a string in R?

Tags: r, string, function, vector, apply

As my question suggests, I have been tasked with writing a function which calls another function at every position of a vector. The following is the original function that I currently have:

```
    find.TATA = function(k,s) {
     v = string.to.vec(s)
     i = v[k:(k+5)]
     TATA = "TATAAA"
     TATA.v = string.to.vec(TATA)
     return(all(i==TATA.v))
    }
```

As you can see, the function takes both a string (in this case a DNA sequence) and a position (k) within the sequence, and returns either TRUE or FALSE depending on whether "TATAAA" occurs at position k.

I was wondering how it would be possible to write a second function which calls the first function at every position in the input string (1:995). The result should return either TRUE or FALSE for every position. I will then modify the function using a dummy variable to count the number of times the result comes up as TRUE. Thanks in advance!

(P.S. Could any solutions please try to avoid using content from packages as we have been told to solve this using base R functionality)

Comment: Can k start at every position in the string (1, 2, 3, ...) or does k increase by 5 for every position (1, 6, 11, ...)?

Comment: so as the "TATAAA" string being looked for is 6 characters long, the function is checking a sub-vector of 6 elements starting from position k. Example, if k =5 the function with check positions 5 to 10 to see if "TATAAA" occurs within this range. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

This is a fairly primitive way of doing things:

```
count.TATA <- function(string) {
  count <- 0
  for (i in 1:nchar(string)-5) {
    if (substr(string, i, i+5) == "TATAAA") {
      count <- count + 1
    }
  }
  return(count)
}
```

Comment: That works brilliantly thank you! Just as a follow up, how would I go about applying this function to multiple randomly generated strings? So for example, I have a random.dna(x) function which returns a string of random dna bases of length x, and I would like to apply your function to 1000 of these random.dna strings?

Comment: I assume you have these 1000 strings stored in some kind of list or vector? You can try something like `sapply(random.dna.vec, count.TATA)`

Comment: Great I'll give that a go. Thank you very much!